# React/TypeScript typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

type InputProps = JSX.IntrinsicElements["input"];

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
  return <input {...props} type={"text"} />;
};

const TextInput: React.FC<
  InputProps & { value: string; onChange: (value: string) => void }
> = ({ onChange = undefined, ...props }) => {
  return <Input {...props} onChange={(e) => onChange?.(e.target.value)} type={"text"}/>;
};

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} placeholder={"type..."}/>
      {/* Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.typescript(2345) */}
      <TextInput value={textValue} onChange={(value) => setTextValue(value)} placeholder={"type..."}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Сode works fine, but I get a type error. I want to override the default behavior on onChange and reuse the base component. My TypeScript is swearing

`Argument of type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<string>'.typescript(2345)`.

I haven't found anywhere to override types, I can only do Unions and Intersection which really frustrates me. I could also do Omit, but that would take a lot of code for me. Sorry if there is a rerun and simple solution, I haven't found any

Comment: Write a title that summarizes the specific problem. The title is the first thing that potential answerers will see. If your title isn’t interesting, they won’t read the rest. Also, without a good title, people may not even be able to find your question. So, *make the title count*. **Pretend you’re talking to a busy colleague** and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence. **Don’t include tags in the title**. If you’re having trouble summarizing the problem, **write the title *last***.

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

```
const TextInput: React.FC<
  Omit<InputProps, 'onChange'> & { value: string; onChange: (value: string) => void }
> = ({ onChange = undefined, ...props }) => {
  return <Input {...props} onChange={(e) => onChange?.(e.target.value)} type={"text"}/>;
};
```